# What is the importance of average in performance metrics?

Tags: performance

As part of the performance tuning and load tests we usually do, i am forced to believe that we need to look at 90th percentiles. As per my understanding 90 times out of hundred people got a respone which is equal to or better than the 90th percentile number. However my current clients always look at average number.What is the impact of only looking at average? Most of the times, I see that between two tests, if average is lower in test A , then 90th percentile is also less in test A.

So should we match the SLA on average or on 90th percentile?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the help centre.  It's not a matter of trying to write code or to correct already written code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is not a pure programming question. But in my humble opinion, program performance and statistics are closely related anyway. That's why I think this question deserves an answer.

The two are different in nature. We then have the average - the sum of all observations divided by the number of observations. We also have the median or 50 percentile - half of the observations are above, half are below.
There's a very visible difference in the two if your observations do not match the bell curve: e.g. if you have positive outliers but no negative outliers.

Let's do a few number examples:

- observations 2 4 6 8 - average and median are both 5
- observations 1 1 10 - average is 4, median is 1. 
  Your 50 percentile could be argued on any number between 1 and 10 here: two observations are below, one is above for any of these numbers.
- observations 1 4 1000 - average is 335, median is 4, 50 percentile is also 4.

As you can see, the distribution of the numbers matters a lot.
Only if you have a symmetrical distribution (like a Gaussian bell curve), the average equals the 50 percentile.

But you asked for the 90 percentile.
Essentially, nothing changes - the distribution, the number of outliers and the most often observed values affect your percentile.

I suggest to pick up a good book on statistics if you need to know more.